# JS code to flowchart containing functions

Tags: javascript

I need to construct the flowchart of this JS code. I can't understand how I should include functions in flowchart, any ideas?

```
    function someYear(year) {
    return(year%4 == 0);
}
function someMonth(month, year) {
    if (month == 1) {
        return "January";
    }
    else if (month == 3) {
        return "March";
    }
    else if (month == 2 && someYear(year)) {
        return "February" + y;
    }
    else if (month == 2 && someYear(year) == false) {
        return "February";
    }
    else {
        return "The month is not in list";
    }
}
console.log(someMonth(2, 2007));
```

Comment: To make it clear, do you want to write a JS function that takes some code as an input and returns a flowchart ? Or is it something else that you want ?

Comment: No, I just need the flowchart of the code provided above.

Answer (score 1):

I think **[this image](https://bournetocode.com/projects/GCSE_Computing_Fundamentals/pages/img/Subroutines_Flowchart_Example.png)** will give you the idea.

Comment: Glad that it helped. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use the functional representation that is used in the comment of @seymurium, or you can represent the logic that lies under the target function directly instead of the function body.

In your case `someMonth()` function needs to be replaced with 5 **conditional statements**.